# How to make a normal interface for a 2D project in Unity 2022

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a 2d project in unity, as a result, a project with such an interface was created (1 photo)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyZkx.png), while everyone creates a standard project with the usual familiar interface.(photo 2) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4fRT.png)

Before that, I did a 3d project, everything was fine. I have recreated the project many times, even reinstalled unity. All without success. Please tell me, maybe I'm just crooked and don't understand something

Comment: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/exploring-the-editor-layout#6009e99aedbc2a3e851af455

Answer (score 1):

Right up click to Layout and you can chose what sort of layout you want. Additionally, game window is covering all scene thus it looks all blue.

- you can simply left click drag and drop the window
- you can grab from sides and arrange the window size
- you can right click on window name and close it and reactive from above "window" drop  down menu.

please also see attached images.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the very top-right corner of unity and click on **"Layout"**. There you can click through the different layouts for your unity workflow like **"Default"** or **"2 by 3"**. This should bring back the view that you are familiar with.
Can also be found under **Unity->Window->Layout->Default**.

From the screenshot you provided it also seems like you closed all your panels like "Scene","Hierarchy" and "inspector". To get them back click on **Unity->Window->Panels->Scene/Game/Hierarchy...** this way you can add back each individual view.

I stick 90% of the time to the same layout, but there you can try out the different premade settings. From there you can also adjust the layout by dragging the window frames bigger or smaller. Save your changes to a new custom layout or start over by selecting a default layout again.

If you want to learn more about the Unity Editor Layout visit this website:
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/exploring-the-editor-layout